# What is the use of SCRAM-SHA-256 (over SCRAM-SHA-1)?

Tags: hash, authentication, sha-256, sha-1, challenge-response

The Salted Challenge Response Authentication Mechanism (SCRAM) specified in [RFC 5802](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5802) can use arbitrary hash functions to operate. The base version from RFC 5802 uses SHA-1.

From my understanding, SCRAM solely relies on the one-way-ness of the function. It does not need collision resistance. It uses extensive salting and possibly many iterations, as well as a clever nonce-based mechanism to thwart replays.

In a discussion about which SCRAM version to recommend, somebody asked why SCRAM-SHA-256 ([RFC 7677](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7677)) should be used at all (even why it was even specified); aren’t the improved security properties of SHA-256 over SHA-1 irrelevant for the SCRAM use-case? Is this simply future-proofing?

RFC 7677 states in the Security Considerations:

> See [RFC4270] and [RFC6194] for reasons to move from SHA-1 to a
> strong security mechanism like SHA-256.

[RFC 6194](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6194) has the following:

> **3.  SHA-1 Security Considerations**
>
> [collision resistance and pre-image considerations for SHA-1]
>
> **3.3.  HMAC-SHA-1**
>
> As of today, there is no indication that attacks on SHA-1 can be
> extended to HMAC-SHA-1.

Note that SCRAM uses the hash function mostly in an HMAC construct; the only exception is `StoredKey := H(ClientKey)`, but `StoredKey` is never transmitted over the wire and only used as key in an HMAC round. However, `StoredKey` is stored on the server. I don’t think that a pre-image to `StoredKey` would be useful, because in the protocol one needs both `StoredKey` and `ClientKey` to form the `ClientProof`.

[RFC 4270](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4270) is less specific about the hash functions and talks in more generality about how they are used in the IETF protocols and how the attacks affect those uses.

From what I can tell, we can consider two uses of the hash function in SCRAM-SHA-1: 1. The obfuscation of the password through PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA-1 as pseudo-random function, 2. challenge/response mechanism using HMAC-SHA-1.

Both uses are not mentioned as problematic in RFC 4270, AFAICT.

So to summarize, from what I have gathered:

- SCRAM-SHA-256 uses a more expensive algorithm, without apparent security benefits
- migration from SCRAM-SHA-1 to SCRAM-SHA-256 is difficult (requires a password change -> user interaction)

So... From that, the only use for SCRAM-SHA-256 seems to be new deployments and future-proofing, is that right? Is there a conceivable weakness of SCRAM-SHA-1 which outweighs the loss of interoperability when moving to or deploying SCRAM-SHA-256?

Answer (score 3):

Nobody should use a primitive which is known to be broken in any new development or deployment. Anything involving SHA-1 is basically deprecated at this point.

A break in collision-resistance is a crack that might be exploited further by follow-on research; this happened with other hash functions in the past. [Attacks only get better, they never get worse](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html).

Besides, SCRAM-SHA-1 really isn’t deployed widely enough  for interoperability to matter.

Comment: "SCRAM-SHA-1 really isn’t deployed widely enough for interoperability to matter" I don’t think that’s true everywhere. For example, in XMPP, SCRAM-SHA-1 [is the only SCRAM mechanism which is currently deployed](https://xmpp.net/reports.php#saslmechanisms), and it is the most widely supported one (aside from PLAIN).